# Does this Funnelytics code contain a race condition?

Tags: javascript, browser, deferred-execution, dynamic-script-loading

I'm looking into tracking scripts that I've come across. Here's one by Funnelytics. At first look it seems like it has a bug:

```
(function(funnel) {
    var insert = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
        script = document.createElement('script');
    script.addEventListener('load', function() {
        window.funnelytics.init(funnel, false);
    });
    script.src = 'https://cdn.funnelytics.io/track.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    insert.parentNode.insertBefore(script, insert);
})('8889dbc2-6c2f-5ba4-c201-dc8889dbc26c');
```

Isn't it possible that the function triggered by `load` will be called before the asynchronous script `track.js` gets executed? In which case, won't the line `window.funnelytics.init` fail, since `window.funnelytics` hasn't been defined yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does **not** contain a race condition. Notice that the event listener is attached to the `script` element, not the `window` object:

```
script.AddEventListener('load', function() { // ...
```

This function will only get called once the script loads and is executed.

Even if the event listener had been attached to the `window` object, this code would still not contain a race condition. The function would only get called once all the `window`'s subresources get loaded and executed, including any `async` scripts that are dynamically inserted, as happens here.